# Calculating Average of Datediff

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my schemas: **employee** and **dept_emp**.

**employee** table contains all employees' data: ***emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date*** (when is employee started working for the company). The **employee** table will some kind looks like this

| emp_no | first_name | last_name | hire_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Liam | Nelson | 1997-01-02 |
| 10002 | Freddie | Mercury | 1998-01-02 |
| 10003 | Phil | Foden | 1999-01-02 |

On another hand, **dept_emp** table shows in which department every employee works in. One employee can work in > 1 dept in different periods of time. For example, Emp 1 can work on Dept 2 from 01-01-1990 until 31-12-1991 then move on to work in Dept 2 from 01-01-1992. The table consists of ***emp_no, dept_no, from_date*** (when that employee started working for that dept), ***to_date*** (when that employee started working for that dept). The **dept_emp** table will some kind looks like this:

| emp_no | dept_no | from_date | to_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 0001 | 1997-01-02 | 9999-01-02 |
| 10002 | 0002 | 1998-01-02 | 1999-03-15 |
| 10002 | 0004 | 1999-03-16 | 2001-01-02 |
| 10003 | 0003 | 1999-01-02 | 2001-04-08 |

Based on the table, For all of the employees that are still currently working for the company, The ***to_date*** field in the **dept_emp** table is filled with '9999-01-01' (to show no resignation date yet) whilst for the employee that has resigned The ***to_date*** field is filled with their resignation date.

Now for the previous case, I had **calculated how many days have every employee worked** for the company **but only for those who already resigned**. I figured out that to achieve the result, I would have to subtract the resignation date from the max(***to_date***) field with the min(***from_date***) using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_no,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.hire_date,
    MAX(d.to_date) AS leave_date,
    DATEDIFF (MAX(d.to_date),MIN(d.from_date)) AS days_employed
FROM
    employees e
        JOIN
    dept_emp d ON e.emp_no = d.emp_no
GROUP BY e.emp_no
HAVING MAX(d.to_date) < SYSDATE()
ORDER BY DATEDIFF (MAX(d.to_date),MIN(d.from_date)) DESC;
```

I have now achieved the number of days worked for all resigned employees. But now I figured out that I wanted to get how long all resigned employees worked for my company on average. I have tried the following code using the *Average* from the *datediff* function but the MySQL workbench says there is something wrong with my syntax and I feel like I'm missing something here:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(DATEDIFF (days, MAX(to_date), MIN(from_date))) AS avg_days_employed
FROM
    dept_emp
HAVING MAX(to_date) < SYSDATE();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel like I'm missing something here

1. You try to use nested aggregate function (`AVG(MAX())`) - this is not allowed.
2. All rows are treated as one group - so if at least one row matches `to_date < SYSDATE()` then the output will be empty.

For to solve you need in subquery:

```sql
SELECT AVG(days_employed) average_days_employed
FROM ( SELECT DATEDIFF (MAX(to_date), MIN(from_date)) AS days_employed
       FROM dept_emp
       GROUP BY emp_no
       HAVING MAX(to_date) < SYSDATE()
     ) subquery;
```

PS. You (and me too) don't take into account the case where the same employee was fired and then rehired.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I noticed that if I delete the 'subquery', the query won't work. Can you explain what the 'subquery' does here?

Comment: @diikuun This is an alias for a subquery. It can be almost any (the requirements are the same as for table names). It is needed for to refer to subquery's column when it have the same name like a column in some another table.

Comment: Ah I see so that is just an alias for subquery, alright thanks!